# Failed to upload image 3 using iPhone app

Tags: bug

This is not a question. The iPhone app failed to upload a third image and popped a dialog telling me to “tell us on meta”.

I was editing a question in Movies & TV that required additional photos.

Comment: I think they mean https://meta.stackexchange.com/ ... as this is not specific to the M&TV site

Comment: I tapped on your link to main meta, and see list of questions but iPhone app interface offers no button to ask a question there. Quite vexing.

Comment: You may need to create an account there.  Its usually easy if you have one here.  I'm guessing this is the issue

Comment: Thanks, I went to Safari [to post.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363692/iphone-app-throws-alert-when-uploading-3rd-image)